# Ant - How can I run the same depends from multiple targets

Tags: ant

Is there a way to get ant to execute multiple depend targets multiple times.  Consider this:

```
<target name="buildall" depends="mycommon,myDAO" />

<target name="myCommon" depends="initCommon, clean, makedir, compile" description="">
    <echo> Build completed for myCommon </echo>
</target>

<target name="myDAO" depends="initDAO, clean, makedir, compile" description="">
    <echo> Build completed for myDao </echo>
</target>
```

I would like buildAll to call myCommon, which calls initCommon, clean, makedir, compile, then call myDAO which calls initDAO, clean, makedire, compile.

So I want the clean, makedir and compile tasks to be executed multiple times.  They are generic and run based on properties set in the initXXX task.

I tried this:

```
<target name="buildall">
    <antcall  target="myCommon" />
    <antcall target="myDao" />
</target>
```

but that runs everything outside of tasks everytime which is not what I want.  Any thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean by "everything outside of tasks everytime"? Seems `<antcall>` works in running the targets as you wish but introduces other problems?

Comment: yes - I have a bunch of <mkdir> and <delete dir=""> tasks as children of the <project> tag.  Maybe that is wrong.  These tasks I want to run once regardless of how many targets I specify.

Comment: the problem is that if I run from eclipse and specify several targets, it only runs the <project> elements once and it runs each target and each of its dependencies (multiple times even if the dependeny has been run before).  When I run in eclipse all is good.  When I run outside of eclipse it doesn't work the same.

Comment: Oh, this problem happens because each time when you invoke `<antcall>`, Ant will create a new `Project` instance for the current build file. In this way, you get the ability to control whether properties and references declared in the calling target (and the ones before it) should be inheritted by the called target -- `inheritAll` and `inheritRefs`. I don't use Eclipse so I don't know what it behaves and why, but your problem is exactly how pure Ant works.

Comment: A very very simple solution: write your own Ant task, maybe named `<runonce>`, give it the abilities to run nested Ant tasks, and in its `execute()` method: 1. check if a system property, e.g. "Ran", is set; 2. if set, return; if not, run nested tasks; 3. set a system property "Ran".

Comment: You had a good idea, but I didn't want to write an ant task.  It got me thinking - so I put all my project level tasks in a new target called prepare with an unless attribute where the property "prepared" is set inside the prepare target.  Then I added prepare as the first dependency to all the other targets - including the buildall target.  Since the prepare target is called by the buildall, the prepared attribute is set and passed to all the antcalls thus causing the prepare target to be ignored.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First: Do not use `<antcall/>` it's usually a sign you've done something wrong.

Now, understand that Ant is not a programming language where you tell Ant what you want to do and the order you want it to be done. Ant is a *matrix dependency language*. You merely tell Ant what you want (I want to build this jar), and let Ant figure out what it should do. Ant does its very best ***not to*** run a target multiple times.

For example, both `myCommon` and `myDAO` call the `clean` target. Ant duly notes that both require `clean` target, and then calls `clean` once and only once before it runs both of your targets. It's the way Ant is suppose to work.

So, let Ant do its job. First, *Thou shall not clean* under normal circumstances. Builds are suppose to minimize rebuilding in order to speed up a task. If you haven't modified a `*.java` file, why should you force me to rebuild the corresponding `*.class` file?

Second: Don't double up dependencies: For example, if I want to build the target `myDAO`, I want to compile the code (maybe build a jar or war). That's all my `myDAO` target should depend upon. Now, when I compile, I might need to make my directory, and when I make my directory, I might need to do my init:

```
<target name="clean">
    <echo>Clean up my working directory to be nice and sparkly</echo>
</target>
<target name="initDAO">
    <echo>Initialize stuff for my DAO build</echo>
    <echo>Maybe setup some properties?</echo>
</target>
<target name="makedir"
     depends="initDAO">
    <echo>I need my directories for building.</echo>
    <echo>But first, I need to setup stuff"</echo>
</target>
<target name="compile"
    depends="makedir">
    <echo>I need to compile my dao source"</echo>
    <echo>But first, I need to make the necessary directories</echo>
<target>
<target name="myDAO"
    depends="compile">
    <echo>Here's where I package up my DAO</echo>
    <echo>But I have to compile stuff before I can package it</echo>
</target>
```

Note the above structure. If I run the target `myDAO`, Ant will look at the dependencies and then run `initDAO`, `makedir`, compile, and finally `myDAO` to package everything up. Again, I have a `clean` target that will restore my working space to pristine (before anything was built) condition, but I don't call it as part of a package because I don't want to redo work.

"Ah!", you say, "But I have to clean up because `myCommon` and `myDAO` use the same directories for building and packaging."

Well don't do that. Instead, make sure your two packages use different *target* directories for building and packaging. This way, you don't have to clean up the mess from one to another. And, you can change a single source file, rebuild, and not have to recompile everything again.

You can save yourself from trouble by defining [macros](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html) to handle stuff in common between the two. For example, you might be able to define a compile macro that takes as its parameters the name of a source directory and it will create a destdir based upon that source directory name and compile your common and `DAO` targets.

So, let Ant work its magic. Use dependencies not as a means of telling Ant how to do something, but merely telling Ant that a particular target depends upon another target. Let Ant figure out the order of execution. Also, don't set up your tasks to require you to scrub directories and reinitialize everything. You want Ant to help minimize the build by not having to rebuild or recopy over files that haven't changed.

Comment: Excellent answer, `antcall` is truly the `GOTO` of ant.

Comment: I see your point.  I think the trick was that most of my tasks (clean, compile, makedir) should have been defined as macros instead of dependent targets.  These tasks (clean, compile, makedir) are generic and operate on variables set in a initXXXX task.  Now we can pass them as paramaters to the macro call.  Much better solution.  Thanks.